# How do I paste source code from clipboard with same formatting

Tags: vim, formatting, paste

I don't know why but `Vim` always mess up my formatting if I am copying code from some external program through `CTRL + V + P` shortcut. For instance this snippet of XML code

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-selenium</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

is copied into Vim like this (sorry for `|` characters, that is from `indentLine` plugin )

```
<dependency>
    │   │   │   │   │   <groupId>org.jboss.test</groupId>
    │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   <artifactId>richfaces-selenium</artifactId>
    │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   <scope>test</scope>
    │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   │   </dependency>
```

So how do I fix this behaviour? Something similar also happens when I paste Java or Python code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `paste` mode in Vim, which disables the auto-indentation. This can be done while in insert mode. `:help paste`

Answer (score 0):

I have always had that problem. Personally I have not tried to fix how I paste it in, but I do a quick fix after I paste it in.

After you past your code, Hit Esc a few times and do this command

```
gg=G
```

Basic breakdown:

```
gg --> Go to beginning of File
=  --> Indent
G  --> Go to end of File
```

Should indent everything correctly, based on your indentation settings on .vimrc (if you have none, then it will just do basic tab indentation).